# Questions on USE OF ENGLISH IN FCE exam

Tags: vocabulary, exam-questions

sorry for the stupid question, but I am preparing the student for FCE and we have such sentence:

As a result ...it..... is common for old people to fall asleep during the day.

Can we use here "that" instead of "it"? If yes, would it be a mistake on the FCE exam to use "that"?

And a few more questions:
It is one of the United Kingdom’s top ten beach
destinations and was recently (2)....voted?......the UK’s Green Capital.

- Can we use here another verb? one-word only ("chosen as" will not work in the FCE)

However, living with someone will put all kinds of pressures
on your (31)....friendship........

- Can we say friendship instead of friendships?

Comment: English Mag, it's best to ask one question at a time. The sentence: **As a result, it is common for old people to fall asleep during the day** is perfectly idiomatic. To replace **it** with **that** would NOT be idiomatic. You should put your other queries as separate questions.

Comment: isn't it possible to send 3 questions in one post? even if to number them from 1 to 3?

Comment: If the three questions are related, you can ask them together. But if they concern different issues, you are expected to ask them separately.